# How to add an AWS EC2 instance on Scalr

Tags: amazon-ec2, scalr

I have an AWS account with 14 instances and using scalr. I added the Api reference details and it showed up, at that time instances were pretty low. As and when I keep adding new instances it accepted few and reject the rest. Now I have an instance newly made on AWS which is not getting loaded in scalr.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're questions is. What do you mean by "I keep adding new instances it accepted few and reject the rest"? Please provide more details.

Comment: I create roles on scalr, for each role a new instance is created.

Comment: When you create a role in scalr, it will launch a new instance in aws so that it can create a snapshot of it for the role. This should only be temporary. Are you able to provide more details? What is your actual question, and what are you trying to do?

Comment: I have linked AWS with Scalr... - > so far, understood? Now... I created an instance on AWS.. a blank one... new.... it is supposed to show up on scalr! But, it doesn't ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instances that you create using AWS will not show up in Scalr.

Instead, you create [`Farms`](http://wiki.scalr.com/display/docs/Farms) (in Scalr) through the use of custom and/or pre-configured Scalr [`Roles`](http://wiki.scalr.com/display/docs/Roles). When you launch those farms/roles, it will launch the required instances in AWS. It's like a wrapper around AWS that provides extra features, **but it will only ever know about instances that have been launched from a Scalr role**.

It is possible to import an existing server into Scalr although it involves installing the scalarizr software onto that server and opening some ports. [Full details can be found here](http://wiki.scalr.com/display/docs/Import+a+non+Scalr+server). Once complete, you'll have a new role that you can add to a farm and then launch.